# How to make children wrap their own width?

Tags: css, react-native, layout, flexbox

I want my children look like this

[image]

not like this

[image]

Here is my code

//i use map to create list of children, i don't use flatlist or other lists due to some purpose

```
<Portal>
    <Modal visible={visibleModal} onDismiss={hideModal} style={styles.modalFilter} contentContainerStyle={styles.contentModalFilter}>
         {genres.map(genre => <Chip key={genre} onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>{genre}</Chip>)}
     </Modal>
</Portal>
```

//css

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 modalFilter: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 30,
 },
 contentModalFilter: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 15,
 },
});
```

Comment: `display: flex` with a `flex-wrap: wrap` on the parent, then on the child *calc* the *minimum width* along with the padding and/or gap depending on how many items you want to fit into the parents width, something like; `min-width: calc(33% - padding)` and then add a flex-basis of 1 `flex-basis: 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 modalFilter: {
    display: flex;
    flexWrap: wrap;
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 30,
 },
 contentModalFilter: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: calc(33% - 40),
    height: '100%',
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 15,
 },
});
```